# OAuth 2.0 Authorization for windows desktop application using HttpListener

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, httplistener

I am writing a windows desktop application with External Authentication(Google, Facebook) in C#.

I'm using HttpListener to allow a user to get Barer token by External Authentication Service with ASP.NET Web API, but administrator privileges are required for that and I want run without admin mode.

My reference was [Sample Desktop Application for Windows](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthDesktopApp).

Is this the best practice for external authentication provider from C#? Or is there another way to do that?

This is my code to get Barer token by external provider:

```
public static async Task<string> RequestExternalAccessToken(string provider)
{
    // Creates a redirect URI using an available port on the loopback address.
    string redirectURI = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", IPAddress.Loopback, GetRandomUnusedPort());

    // Creates an HttpListener to listen for requests on that redirect URI.
    var http = new HttpListener();
    http.Prefixes.Add(redirectURI);
    http.Start();

    // Creates the OAuth 2.0 authorization request.
    string authorizationRequest = Properties.Settings.Default.Server
        + "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider="
        + provider
        + "&response_type=token&client_id=desktop"
        + "&redirect_uri="
        + redirectURI + "?";

    // Opens request in the browser.
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationRequest);

    // Waits for the OAuth authorization response.
    var context = await http.GetContextAsync();

    // Sends an HTTP response to the browser.
    var response = context.Response;
    string responseString = string.Format("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    var responseOutput = response.OutputStream;
    Task responseTask = responseOutput.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        responseOutput.Close();
        http.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.");
    });

    // Checks for errors.
    if (context.Request.QueryString.Get("access_token") == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error connecting to server");
    }

    var externalToken = context.Request.QueryString.Get("access_token");

    var path = "/api/Account/GetAccessToken";

    var client = new RestClient(Properties.Settings.Default.Server + path);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.GET };
    request.AddParameter("provider", provider);
    request.AddParameter("AccessToken", externalToken);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var clientResponse = client.Execute(request);

    if (clientResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(clientResponse.Content);

        return responseObject.access_token;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error connecting to server", clientResponse.ErrorException);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about Facebook, but usually (I am experienced with Google OAuth2 and Azure AD as well as Azure AD B2C), the authentication provider allows you to use a *custom* URI scheme for the authentication callback, something like `badcompany://auth`

To acquire an authentication token I ended up implementing the following scheme (All code is presented without warranty and not to be copied thoughtlessly.)

#### 1. Register an URI-handler when the app is started

You can register an URI-Handler by creating a key in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes` (hence no admin privileges needed) key in the Windows registry

- The name of the key equals the URI prefix, `badcompany` in our case
- The key contains an empty string value named `URL Protocol`
- The key contains a subkey `DefaultIcon` for the icon (actually I do not know whether this is necessary), I used the path of the current executable
- There is a subkey `shell/open/command`, whose default value determines the path of the command to execute when the URI is tried to be opened, **please note*, that the `"%1"` is necessary to pass the URI to the executable

```cs
    this.EnsureKeyExists(Registry.CurrentUser, "Software/Classes/badcompany", "URL:BadCo Applications");
    this.SetValue(Registry.CurrentUser, "Software/Classes/badcompany", "URL Protocol", string.Empty);
    this.EnsureKeyExists(Registry.CurrentUser, "Software/Classes/badcompany/DefaultIcon", $"{location},1");
    this.EnsureKeyExists(Registry.CurrentUser, "Software/Classes/badcompany/shell/open/command", $"\"{location}\" \"%1\"");

// ...

private void SetValue(RegistryKey rootKey, string keys, string valueName, string value)
{
    var key = this.EnsureKeyExists(rootKey, keys);
    key.SetValue(valueName, value);
}

private RegistryKey EnsureKeyExists(RegistryKey rootKey, string keys, string defaultValue = null)
{
    if (rootKey == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Root key is (null)");
    }

    var currentKey = rootKey;
    foreach (var key in keys.Split('/'))
    {
        currentKey = currentKey.OpenSubKey(key, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree) 
                     ?? currentKey.CreateSubKey(key, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (currentKey == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not get or create key");
        }
    }

    if (defaultValue != null)
    {
        currentKey.SetValue(string.Empty, defaultValue);
    }

    return currentKey;
}
```

#### 2. Open a pipe for IPC

Since you'll have to pass messages from one instance of your program to another, you'll have to open a named pipe that can be used for that purpose.

I called this code in a loop in a background `Task`

```cs
private async Task<string> ReceiveTextFromPipe(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string receivedText;

    PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
    System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
    PipeAccessRule par = new PipeAccessRule(sid, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
    ps.AddAccessRule(par);

    using (var pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(this._pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 4096, 4096, ps))
    {
        await pipeStream.WaitForConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
        {
            receivedText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

    return receivedText;
}
```

#### 3. Make sure that the application is started only *once*

This can be acquired using a [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.8).

```
internal class SingleInstanceChecker
{
    private static Mutex Mutex { get; set; }

    public static async Task EnsureIsSingleInstance(string id, Action onIsSingleInstance, Func<Task> onIsSecondaryInstance)
    {
        SingleInstanceChecker.Mutex = new Mutex(true, id, out var isOnlyInstance);
        if (!isOnlyInstance)
        {
            await onIsSecondaryInstance();
            Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
        }
        else
        {
            onIsSingleInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

When the mutex has been acquired by another instance, the application is not fully started, **but**

#### 4. Handle being called with the authentication redirect URI

1. If it's the only (first) instance, it may handle the authentication redirect URI itself

   - Extract the token from the URI
   - Store the token (if necessary and/or wanted)
   - Use the token for requests
2. If it's a further instance

   - Pass the redirect URI to the first instance by using pipes
   - The first instance now performs the steps under *1.*
   - Close the second instance

The URI is sent to the first instance with

```cs
using (var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(this._pipeName))
{
    try
    {
        var millisecondsTimeout = 2000;
        await client.ConnectAsync(millisecondsTimeout);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        onSendFailed();
        return;
    }

    if (!client.IsConnected)
    {
        onSendFailed();
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client))
    {
        writer.Write(stringToSend);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to Paul's excellent answer:

- [Identity Model Libraries](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/WindowsConsoleSystemBrowser) are worth looking at - one of the things they'll do for you is Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) which is recommended for native apps
- My preference is the same as Paul's - to use custom URI schemes - usability is better I think
- Having said that, a loopback solution should work without admin rights for ports greater than 1024

If it helps there is some stuff on my blog about this - including a Nodejs / Electron sample you can run from [here](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) to see what a finished solution looks like.